# WPF MediaElement how to resume playing from where it pause?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, mediaelement

i have 2 buttons , Play and Pause , When i click pause , the music stops and when i click Play  it starts the audio from beginning . I want to do it like when i press Play , it resume from where i have stopped.

```
        private void PlayAudio()
    {


        McMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        McMediaElement.Source = new Uri("../../SingAlong/Food Fit For A King/old king cole.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        McMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayAudio();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        McMediaElement.Pause();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `PlayAudio()` method reloads the media file when you set the `Source` property. This causes your object to play the newly loaded media from the beginning when you call `Play()`. Instead of doing this in the event handler `button1_Click_1`, you should call the `Play()` method only:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    McMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: yeah but when i do that , i click the play button at the start , it won't play any audio out.

Comment: So what you want is a button that has two functions depending on the state of your object. Unfortunately, WPF's `MediaElement` does not have properties that lets you check if it is playing or paused. You could keep track of the state yourself and call `Open()` only when you need to. I don't know how you are setting up your object and its `Source` property, but from the code you have posted, I suggest opening the media file only if the `Source` property is null

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   McMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause;
}
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   McMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Many years have passed, but maybe it will be useful to someone..

This works well for me:

```
    bool isPaused = false;
    
    // Button play
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(!isPaused){
    // Do all what You want
    }
    isPaused = false;
    myMediaElement.Play();
    }
    
    // Button Pause:
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      isPaused = true;
      myMediaElement.Pause();
    }
```